# Maxmind GeoIP city javascript

Tags: asp-classic

I'm trying to implement tha javascript webservices from Maxmind GeoIP City , like described [here](http://www.maxmind.com/app/javascript_city), but they say:

> In order to use this JavaScript on your website, please link back to the www.maxmind.com website

I can't use a link in my code because i need to use a server script to check the city, so I wnated to use some trackback method... but i'm not exactly sure about how to do that.

P.D.: I use Classic ASP in the server.
Anyone can help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

Their site says:

> In order to use this JavaScript on your website, please link back to the www.maxmind.com website, or purchase a JavaScript attribution-free license for $10 per million lookups.

Once you pay and register with them, the code will work.

If you are looking for the free version, you can use [MaxMind GeoLite](http://www.maxmind.com/app/geolite), and call it from the server side (See http://www.maxmind.com/app/csharp)